# php + mysql in a html table calculate a percentage

Tags: php, html, mysql

My current code:

```
<td>
   <?php echo $row['feild1'] + $row['feild2'] + $row['feild3'] + $row['feild4'] + $row['feild5'] + $row['feild6'] + $row['feild7'] + $row['feild8'] + $row['feild9'] + $row['feild10'] + $row['feild11'] + $row['feild12'] + $row['feild13'] + $row['feild14'] / 42; ?>
</td>
```

I'm trying to produce a percentage but it just seems to add the values together.

Comment: Wrap you additions between parentheses before dividing.

Comment: As a percentage of 42? I am assuming 42 must be a total possible grade or the like.

Comment: yeah 42 is the highest possible number that can be achived

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<td><?php echo ($row['feild1'] + $row['feild2'] + $row['feild3'] + $row['feild4'] + $row['feild5'] + $row['feild6'] + $row['feild7'] + $row['feild8'] + $row['feild9'] + $row['feild10'] + $row['feild11'] + $row['feild12'] + $row['feild13'] + $row['feild14']) / 42; ?></td>
```

Like so.

Also you misspelled `field`. Not `feild`.

Answer (score 1):

If all the values in array are numbers (integers or floats); you can use the [`array_sum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```php
<?php echo array_sum($row) / 42; ?>
```

or maybe

```php
<?php echo array_sum($row) / (count($row) * 4); ?>
```